# TFS user cannot set permission for create tag for other users

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have some users who are members of a group I have created. The group has most permissions enabled (set to Allow) including both "Create tag definition" and "Edit project-level information". The idea was to put certain users in a group that has permission to administer certain aspects of a project without adding them to the built in Project Administrator group.

However although these users can add users and groups and do MOST things they cannot set the "Create tag definitions" for users in groups or teams they create. To allow this single permission they need to be a member of the Project Administrators group.

Can someone explain why this specific permission is treated differently from all the other permission that seem to be controlled by the "Edit project-level information". Is there a way to permit users to control this specific permission for other users in a project without having to be a member of the Project Administrators group.

Comment: What's the result when you using tf  command ?https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd

Answer (score 1):

No, you must be a member of Project Administrators group.

Although the Create tag definition permission appears in the security settings at the team project level, tagging permissions are actually collection-level permissions that are scoped at the project level when they appear in the user interface. To scope tagging permissions to a single team project when using the TFSSecurity command, you must provide the GUID for the project as part of the command syntax. Otherwise, your change will apply to the entire team project collection. Keep this in mind when changing or setting these permissions.

Comment: I get it. I was hoping I was missing something. This seems like a permission that should NOT require a person to be a member of the project admin group.